# Как "безопасно" получить значение по индексу в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
_list = [5, 6, 9, 8, 1]
print(_list[6])
```

Вверху приведен код при исполнении которого будет ошибка - **IndexError: list index out of range**. Как мне написать код, которые при ошибке выдаст какое-то заранее установленное значение.

```
dict.get("key", "значения нет") # < Как нибудь так, но только со списком
```

Или единственный вариант это.

```
try: ... 
except IndexError: ...
```

Просто странно что у словаря такое есть, а списку не добавили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так а в чём проблема? Напишите свою функцию и в ней делайте проверку. Пример:

```
def get_element_list(lst: list, index: int, value=None):
    if index > len(lst) - 1:
        return value
    return lst[index]


_list = [5, 6, 9, 8, 1]
print(get_element_list(_list, 6))  # > None
```

Если вы не часто выходите за край списка то можно отлавливать ошибку:

```
def get_element_list(lst: list, index: int, value=None):
    try:
        return lst[index]
    except IndexError:
        return value
```

В идеале создать свой класс наследуясь от листа, где мы реализуем недостающий метод:

```
class MyList(list):
    def get(self, index: int, value=None):
        if index > len(self) - 1:
            return value
        return self[index]


_list = MyList([5, 6, 9, 8, 1])
print(_list.get(6))  # > None
```